# jquery & php poll in Blogger

Tags: php, jquery, blogger

Would it be possible to use a poll like this in Blogger?

Link:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

As @dazmax said that "you do not have access to a database with Blogger." So as an alternative you can use many poll services out there to create free polls and embed polls widget in your blogger blog.

Some FREE poll services are:

1. [ProProfs Polls](http://www.proprofs.com/polls/)
2. [PollDaddy](http://www.polldaddy.com/)
3. [Pollsb](http://www.pollsb.com/)

So, just create your poll there and get your poll's widget and embed it in your blog.